# Number 6 finger notation on music?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, tuplet

My music has a number 6 on the finger notation and I can’t figure out what finger I’m supposed to use. [image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Music.SX! This is not a fingering number, but rather it tells you that the six notes are to be considered a tuplet. Being a sextuplet, you should play the six notes below the beam in the time ordinarily given to four notes of the same value. The numbers for the fingering are here below the notes.

Comment: 6 notes per beat, assuming quarter note =  1 beat.  You didn't show the time sig.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are one of King Henry's wives, you don't need to worry too much!! The '6' there is indicating six notes in the time of four. Like double triplets.Called *sextuplets* in the trade.

It looks like a slightly different font from the fingerings on the music stave - and again different on the tab.

The lower numbers are the suggested fingerings.

Comment: Actually, number 2 and 5 would be more problematic.

Comment: Do you want to add the terminology, Tim (sextuplets)?

Comment: @aparente001 What's wrong with terminology? Once you know what something is called you can refer to it and mentally compartmentalise (horrible word) it.

Comment: @Peter - probably thinks there's nothing wrong with it - just needed putting into the answer.